# Unable to assign value from record set to vba variable (error -2147217887 (80040e21))

Tags: sql, excel, vba, format

I have an excel workbook, for many reasons I am using sql into excel to loop through fields, the workbook, contains values about employees.

I created a record set from the sheet that I am working on with this request :

```
 Set rst = OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Feuil1$]")
```

this will load my sheet into a record set.

everything were making well till I passed my excel to a friend and he copy pasted data from another sheet into my excel and launched my macro and here I discovered a bug.

When I reach the column "G" Client the line number 13, and try to assign it to a variable, i get an error

[image]

I have a variable called Client in which I fill the value of the field client

```
Dim rst As Object
Dim Client As Variant
Set rst = OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Feuil1$]")

 While Not rst.EOF
...
Client = rst.Fields("Client").Value
..
 rst.movenext
Wend 
Set rst = Nothing
```

the line of code causing the error is :

```
Client = rst.Fields("Client").Value
```

I get an error telling -2147217887 (80040e21)

"you cannot record changes because a value you entered violates the settings defined for this table or list (for example, a value is less than the minimum or greater than the maximum). correct the error and try again"

[image]

*Sorry the message in the screen capture is in french cuz the workbook that i am working on it is french but here is the translation to english*

This made me trying to understand what has specific the line 13 in the column "G"

First of all I can see that this problem appears at the first line filled with data (ATS) in that colum which is the line 13 ..  the previous cells in previous lines were empty and the code was working fine till line 13.

```
Client = rst.Fields("Client").Value
```

At my own original sheet, there is no kind of error, the error came just after my friend copy/pasted his own values into the sheet, and after looking deeply I noticed that after he copy/pasted the data, the format of the cells in the colum G changed to numbers (double) as seen in this picture

[image]

But my variable is variant, so it should accept any kind of data (empty or not, double or not) that's why I can't understand why it's giving this problem ?

I said maybe Excel is not loading into the record set the value ATS, maybe it's loading inside the Rs a kind of special error or something like that, so that the variant variable can't contains it and give this error, I really don't know that why I am asking if you have any clue about this error and how to solve it by code because I simply can solve it manually by changing back to what was the format of my cells before that my friend pasted his data, so if i change the format to Normal instead of decimal in excel cells the problem is solved, but what I want to know is to understand why this error, and how to solve it by CODE inside vba not excel sheet and why a variant variable won't accept a string value (ATS) even if the format in excel is decimal ?

One last thing, i tried to do something like the following but still getting the same error

```
If Not IsError(rst.Fields("Client").Value) Then Client = rst.Fields("Client").Value Else Client= vbNullString
```

Also, If I add a spy to the line causing the problem, I find inside the value, the same error message shown in my vba msgbox, here is a printscreen

[image]

: "

"you cannot record changes because a value you entered violates the settings defined for this table or list (for example, a value is

thanks in advance to anyone who will have a constructive and usefull answer.

Comment: Break on error and verify what the value is that's violating the table constraints. Is it `ADODB.DBNull`?

Comment: Thanks, I will add to my question a printscreen what I am getting inside the spy, but what there is inside the value as it seems is the same error message that I get in vba, dunno if it answer your question